# `task stage` from groovy to kotlin for build.gradle.kts

Tags: gradle, heroku, build.gradle

[Heroku deploying Instruction](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-gradle-apps-on-heroku#verify-that-your-build-file-is-set-up-correctly) says, that I have to add such code to my `build.gradle` file:

```
task stage(dependsOn: ['build', 'clean'])
build.mustRunAfter clean
```

But I have just a `build.gradle.kts` file. How to translate this code from `groovy` to `kotlin`?

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in the Kotlin DSL would be:

```
tasks {
    val stage by registering {
        dependsOn(build, clean)
    }
    build {
        mustRunAfter(clean)
    }
}
```